# Efficient way to compare to zero

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

Condition: having a cycle where I do something if some numeric variable(i.e. `moreThanZero` ) is not a zero(usually more than...). Many-many cycles, say more than a million, what is the most efficient/fast way to compare:

```
if ( !moreThanZero ) { ... }
if ( moreThanZero > 0 ) { ... }
if ( moreThanZero != 0 ) { ... }
if ( moreThanZero !== 0 ) { ... }
```

thanks to @torazaburo

```
if ( 0 !== moreThanZero ) { ... }
```

or other options?

Comment: Worry about correctness, the performance difference here is not important.

Comment: Answering such questions is what `jsperf` is for, although it doesn't really matter. Personally, I'd go for the first solution in the interest of conciseness. If you *are* going to use one of the following three, there are some people out there who would claim that `0 !== moreThanZero` is better practice.

Comment: @torazaburo always was interested about this construction, where zero is LHS of the comparison, but don't use because don't understand how is it better

Comment: @elclanns is correct.  the perf diff here is not interesting

Comment: @NikTerentyev Because you can see what is being compared to more easily, without reading all the way to the end of the condition. Similar idea is the common construct `'string' === typeof foo`. However, I don't use this myself either, because it just feels sort of unnatural to me.

Comment: @torazaburo [Yoda conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) have some minor benefits, but people don't expect it and clear, predictable code is a Very Good Thing. I prefer a good lint tool to warn you of assignments within a conditional, avoiding the issue without doing anything unusual.

Comment: @ssube Thanks for providing the name for this and the link, and pointing out that one side-benefit is avoiding accidental assignments, but overall I agree with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably micro-optimizing and unlikely to see any major difference in a large program from the cost of one comparison against zero. However, for the sake of science...

Tweaking the benchmark written by @AbrahamAdam to prevent most common optimizations (optimizing the loop out, removing variable writes, etc) and just calling a blackhole(ish) function instead, I see a probably significant difference: http://jsperf.com/comparetozero1/3

Speculating as to why the results pan out they way they do:

`!n` is the least-specific operation tested. At the very least, it has to (in some fashion) treat the variable as a boolean. While some optimization can be done and some compilers may be smart enough to use a bitwise not or numeric comparison, the language allows much more work to be done.

`===` and `!==` explicitly don't do type coercion, so they are likely to be reliably fast, with the caveat that both operands must be the same type or they aren't equal. For numbers, this likely becomes an integer comparison, which should map down to the `cmp` instruction.

`>` may, and in modern browsers likely does, take advantage of optimizations when both operands are known to be numeric and especially integral. Comparing against a constant, especially 0, is an ideal case: there's an assembly instruction that compares to 0.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsperf.com/comparetozero1

the difference seems to tiny to make a difference , I would go for comparing the type too with === , because 0 == '' is true

Comment: I see a noticeable difference after tweaking the benchmark to prevent loop removal and other optimizations: http://jsperf.com/comparetozero1/3

Comment: Minor point, but a true comparison would involve values of `moreThanZero` which were not numbers, because the `!=` version will try to cast that to a number before doing the comparison.

Comment: @ssube `(!n)` - 12% slower... hmm. i presume casting is responsible for that.

Comment: slightly unexpected that value and type is the fastest, maybe it's slower in none chrome browsers

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are talking about loops, and a comparing variable in it.
If so,
If you want to compare a variable in a loop of millions of iteration, I would like you to prefer this.

```
 if ( moreThanZero > 0 ) 
 {
 // Your code goes here.......
 }
```

Because,

**if ( !moreThanZero ) { //Do something }** says Do  something if moreThanZero is not zero. It doesn't mean that moreThanZero is Greater than zero, it might be Less than zero too..
**if ( moreThanZero != 0 ) { ... }** will also be discarded for the same reason.
So,  **if ( moreThanZero > 0 ){.....}** might be the answer you were expecting.

Comment: The OP explicitly stated that his goal was to check "not a zero".

Comment: @Nik Terentyev Yeah..! what torazaburo told makes sense then